# I am having trouble placing strings into a vector string

Tags: c++, string, vector

For some strange reason the original string that is meant to be split into various other strings and placed within a vector string using a delimiter does not work all that well. And I can't seem to find my mistake.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string target, string delimiter);

int main()
{
    split ("1,2,3,4,5",",");
    return 0;
}

vector<string> split(string target, string delimiter)
{
    vector<string> word;
    string letter;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while (target[i] != '\0')
    {
        word.empty();
        word.push_back("target");
        while (target[i] != delimiter[0])
        {
            letter = target[i];
            i++;
        }
        word[i]=letter;
        i++;

    }
    return (word);
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: I guess `split ("1,2,3,4,5"," ");` - splitting a comma-separated list by spaces, that may not be what you want.

Comment: Also, delimiter should probably be a char, as you only use the first letter anyway.

Comment: Furthermore, when compiling using `clang++ -Wall`, I get an `unused variable: k` warning.

Comment: `word.push_back("target");` is another problem, perhaps knowing the difference between a variable and its name would be helpful...

Comment: The question in the textbook states that I need to make the delimiter a string for some reason.

Comment: with the split ("1,2,3,4,5"," "); I was checking something out. i changed that back to what it was sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is when you call `split`, the second parameter is a string containing a single space but the string you are splitting is delimited with commas. The other problems which have already been mentioned by [H2CO3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529758/h2co3) in the comments section are highlighted below for completeness.

1. You are emptying the vector during every iteration of the while loop.
2. You are adding the string "target" during every iteration.
3. You are adding a single letter to the vector. You should instead be adding the entire string.
4. You are not taking into account that the delimiter and the individual strings you are extracting may be larger than a single character.
5. The overall logic for matching the delimiter in the string is wrong (at least for the way you have it currently implemented). You are only comparing the first character, if that's the desired behavior change the type of `delimiter` to `string::value_type`.
6. Not a problem per-se but I recommend passing the strings by `const` reference instead of by value since `split` does not require or make a copy of either one.

The example below should help you better understand how you can leverage functionality that already exists in the standard library. It uses the `find` and `substr` member functions of `std::string` rather than directly accessing the data directly. I recommend that you review the documentation for [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) before you go any further.

```
std::vector<std::string>
    split(const std::string& target, const std::string& delimiter)
{
    std::vector<std::string> word;
    size_t start = 0;

    for(;;)
    {
        size_t loc = target.find(delimiter, start);

        if(loc == std::string::npos)
        {
            word.push_back(&target[start]);
            break;
        }

        word.push_back(target.substr(start, loc - start));
        start += (loc - start) + delimiter.size();
    }

    return (word);
}
```